# Cannot obtain a generalized state space averaged model for simple wireless power transfer system

Tags: circuit-analysis, modeling, small-signal, wireless-charging, state-space

this is the first time I ask a question. I am currently working on finding a state space model of the following system :
[image]

where \$U_i\$ is a square wave of amplitude \$U_{in}\$.
This circuit represents a wireless power transfer system with \$U_i\$ coming from a full-bridge inverter, and then a coil system for wireless transfer. The transformer on this circuit is modeled by its T-Transformer equivalent circuit with turns ratio 1.

I want to have a model $$\dot{X} = AX + Bu \\ y = CX +Du$$ where my input would be the amplitude \$U_{in}\$ of the square wave \$U_i\$ and the output would be the amplitude of the voltage across \$R_L\$ or the amplitude of the current \$i_2\$.

Now my input \$U_{in}\$ is an amplitude and not \$U_i\$ directly, which means my circuit is non linear. A common approach would be to use generalized state space averaging and consider the first Fourier coefficients as state variables.

For the implementation, I am following this paper, which has the simplest approach and the most resemblant circuit to mine titles : "Bi-directional Contactless Inductive Power Transfer System
Modeling and verifying" by Bai Liangyu, Tang Houjun and Liu Chao.

So the first step is to write the circuit equations which I obtain as following :

$$\frac{di_1}{dt} = \frac{L_2}{L_e}U_i - R_1\frac{L_2}{L_e}i_1 + \frac{M}{L_e}(R_2+R_L)i_2 - \frac{L_2}{L_e}U_1 +\frac{M}{L_e}U_2$$

$$\frac{di_2}{dt} = -\frac{M}{L_e}U_i + R_1\frac{M}{L_e}i_1 - \frac{L_1}{L_e}(R_2 + R_L)i_2 + M\frac{M}{L_e}U_1 -\frac{L_1}{L_e}U_2$$

$$c_1\frac{di_1}{dt} = i_1$$

$$c_2\frac{di_2}{dt} = i_2$$

Now I apply generalized state space averaging (GSSA) and consider the first Fourier series coefficient as my state variables. Following the strategy of GSSA, I decompose each first coefficient into Real and Imaginary part, which in turn gives me :
$$X = [Re<i_1>_1, Im<i_1>_1, Re<U_1>_1, Im<U_1>_1, Re<i_2>_1, Im<i_2>_1, Re<U_2>_1, Im<U_2>_1 ]^T$$

From the previously cited paper, I know that \$<U_{i}>_1 = -\frac{2j}{\pi}\$.

Using the system equations, I obtain the following A matrix :

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-R_1\frac{L_2}{L_e} & w & -\frac{L_2}{L_e} & 0 & \frac{M}{L_e}(R_2+R_L) & 0 & \frac{M}{L_2} & 0 \\\\
-w & -R_1\frac{L_2}{Le} & 0 & \frac{-L_2}{L_e} & 0 & \frac{M}{L_e}(R_2 +R_L) & 0 & \frac{M}{L_e} \\\\
\frac{1}{c_1} &0 & 0 &w & 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\\\
0 & \frac{1}{c_1} & -w &0 & 0 &0 &0 &0 \\\\
\frac{R_1M}{L_e} & 0 & \frac{M}{L_e} & 0 & -\frac{L_1}{L_e}(R_L+R_2) & w & -\frac{L_1}{L_e} & 0 \\\\
 0 & \frac{R_1M}{L_e} & 0 & \frac{M}{L_e} & -w & \frac{-L_1}{L_e}(R_2 + R_L) & 0 & -\frac{L_1}{L_e} \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c_2} & 0 & 0 & w \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c2} & -w & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I also obtain the following B matrix :
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{2L_2}{\pi L_e} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2M}{L_e\pi} & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^T
$$

Now I can choose the output of my system. Following the paper again, in order to reconstruct the current \$i_2\$, I need \$Re<i_2>_1\$ and  \$Im<i_2>_1\$ because
$$i_2 = 2Re<i_2>_1cos(wt) - 2Im<i_2>_1sin(wt) $$

Now I noticed that \$Im<i_2>_1\$ is always 0 so I just considered 2$Re<i_2>_1, which should reflect the amplitude of the output current of my system.

I modeled the system in simulink/simscape and compared the current from my state space model. I realise that they are not the same. Is there anything wrong with my methodology ?

Comment: It seems that you are not modelling the coil diameters or inter-coil distance so, how is this approach seen to be useful?

Comment: Hello Andy. I think the coil diameters and the inter-coil distance will determine the values of L1 and L2 and M.

Comment: OK point taken but, when I model this type of set-up I take a more pragmatic approach and calculate the coupling coefficient directly. Then it's a simple case of using a simulation tool to extract what voltage appears on the output for a given load and input voltage/current. You'll also inevitably find that the output capacitor really does need to be in parallel and not series as you have shown it.